# Recursion early stage

Tags: c++, function, recursion

```
static int counter;

int collatz(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
        return counter;

    else if(n%2==0) //if n is even
    {
        counter += 1;
        collatz(n/2);
    }
    else
    {
        counter += 1;
        collatz(3*n+1);
    }
}
```

I started with recursion. First I made a factorial program and now this.

Why am I getting error ***Control may reach end of non-void function***

Comment: You forgot to `return` from your function in some branches.

Comment: Just to be a little clearer: this is not an error but rather a warning: the code will still compile although it is likely to give undefined behavior

Comment: Your function does not return on all branches. It should.

Comment: You should also initialize your counter variable to 0.

Comment: @MikeBorkland: that **static** variable is zero initialized.

Comment: You probably should wrap that code into a class to avoid that global variable.

Comment: @Jarod42 I didn't get you. I know what's a class is and it's implementation but wrapping my code around a class?

Comment: @AliHasan: I mean something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c09bf952295d4944)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns nothing in case when initially `n` is not equal to `1` though the function has the return type `int`.

And it is too complicated and uses a global variable.

The function can look as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned int collatz( unsigned int n )
{
    return n < 2 ? 0 : 1 + collatz( n % 2 ? 3 * n + 1 : n / 2 );
}   

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "collatz( 10 ) = " << collatz( 10 ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
collatz( 10 ) = 6
```

Take into account that it is better to use an unsigned integer type as the type of the parameter and returning value instead of a signed integer type. And do not forget that the argument can be set to `0`.

Comment: Using global variable is a problem?

Comment: @AliHasan For starters it is a bad style of programming. You should remember to reset the global variable each time when the function is called. And it is the recursive function that shall return the corresponding value.

Comment: @AliHasan It is my answer is the best because only in my answer there is shown a correct implementation of the function. All other implementations are invalid because the argument can be either zero or a negative number.

Comment: @AliHasan yes, it's not thread safe and if you call collatz(n) again, you need to reset it to 0 again, which is ok here but quite unnecessary.

Comment: @SaileshD I need to reset what to 0? And what does thread safe mean?

Comment: @AliHasan you need to reset the counter to 0 when you are making another call to the same function.. when two different threads call `collatz`, they both will modify the counter and output won't be same as expected.

Comment: @SaileshD Why would I need to reset it. I need to count the number of steps. Every time an if condition is true counter is incremented and returned when n=1

Comment: @AliHasan Try for example to run this loop for ( int i = 0; i < 11; i++ ) { collatz( i ); std::cout << counter << std::endl; } using the implementations shown in other answers.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Okay got it. Thanks a lot. From where can I practice to get these small concepts right and I have heard from many people that I write "complicated" code. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

you should put `return` on all possible outcomes given by your if statements

```
static int counter;

int collatz(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
        return counter;

    else if(n%2==0) //if n is even
    {
        counter += 1;
        return collatz(n/2);
    }
    else
    {
        counter += 1;
        return collatz(3*n+1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You *must return an `int` value* from the function `int collatz(int n)`. In case of `n` is not `1`, you are not returning any value from function `int collatz(int n)`.

To solve this problem add `return` statement in function `int collatz(int n)`.
Following is corrected code:

```
int collatz(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
        return counter;

    else if(n%2==0) //if n is even
    {
        counter += 1;
        return collatz(n/2);
    }
    else
    {
        counter += 1;
        return collatz(3*n+1);
    }
}
```